# Create word report programatically using crystal report on VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

Can i create a word report programatically using crystal report on visual studio ?? is there any api to do this ? like using apache poi api in java ?? code to set text, and create document as the example in the link http://tkgospodinov.com/writing-microsoft-word-documents-in-java-with-apache-poi-part-2-creating-tables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the crystal report to word by adding this code:

```
   YourReportObject.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, Response, True, "FileName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Crystal does not support MS Word 2013 `docx` format. You always have to run MS Word in compatibility mode.